# What's the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

> • We'll taste **the** dishes of different restaurants there.
>
> • We'll taste dishes of different restaurants there.

Are they both grammatically correct? And if they are, what's the difference in meaning between them?

Comment: 'Plat' is not an English word.

Comment: @micheal Harvey I was studying French and mixed the two words lol. I corrected it.